# How to make an expanding navigation bar

Tags: flutter, uinavigationbar, uitabbar, tabbar, flutter-animation

I am trying to create an expanding navigation bar. You can see the sketch I've made below.

[image]

I just can't find any way to build a custom navigation bar like that.
Does anyone know how to build it + animate a transition? I want it to slide up and down after the arrow in the middle got pressed.

Comment: Please check the question guidelines. Your question doesn't follow the format and is likely to go unanswered if you don't improve it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

I think what your looking for is a `DraggableScrollableSheet`. Here is the documentation to it: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html

Comment: can I turn it into a navigation bar tho?

Comment: Sure, just navigate to whatever page when a button on the sheet is clicked

Comment: your welcome, if it fixed your problem please hit the green check mark and accept as answer. Thanks :)